# SQL Between Alphanumeric value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have an Alphanumeric column in my db table. For my filter, I was using between to get the result filter value. Everything is okay. But, In some cases it misses some of the data's from filtering. Here are my samples,

**Sample data**

```
ACQPO14
002421
ACQPO8
ACQPO14
ACQPO19
DUMMY0001
```

**Sql Query**

```
SELECT po.No,
   po.PoS
FROM PoDetails pod
INNER JOIN Pors po ON po.Id=PoD.PoId
WHERE po.No BETWEEN 'ACQPO1' AND 'ACQPO20'
```

For the above sample. the query returns only **ACQPO14** and **ACQPO19** NOT **ACQPO8**.

Any help to this issue will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "ACQP" is fixed or any logic behind..

Comment: @Deva Syntax for the solution will depend on the DBMS. What are you using MySQL?

Comment: 014 is 14, 019 is 19 and 08 is 80 so this number not should be in that interval

Comment: No .. I am sorry. I didn't get your question before. `ACQPO` is not fixed. It can be anything. Because its a user defined or user inputted value. Like, `BCD0101`, `ACQPO5435`, `00003MBN`, `534bvmb`.

Comment: Why do you expect ACQPO8 in the output? It is not alphabetically between 'ACQPO1' AND 'ACQPO20'. (I think that @Justin means the same, but numbers are irrelevant here.)

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense as it is just text.

`1` comes before `8` so, ordering in text (left to right) the db will disregard the last digit of `ACQPO14` to compare it against `ACQPO8`. So `ACQPO1` (`4` removed) comes before `ACQPO8` and `ACQPO2` (`0` removed) comes before `ACQPO8` as well. So it gets filtered out by the `between`.

The only way for you to fix this is to parse the column by splitting it. EG: If `ACQPO` is a fixed-length prefix you can use some DBMS function (you haven't specified any) to trim that part and turn into a numeric format the rest. Then compare/filter by that numeric remainder.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I decided to clarify this answer a bit.

When comparing strings SQL Server is alphabetizing based on the Collation setting. When comparing two strings it doesn't strip characters from the longer string, it effectively pads the shorter out with the first character of your collation. So `ACQP08` might become `ACQP08 ` before it's compared to `ACQP020`

Here is the order:

`002421, --ACQPO1--, ACQPO14, ACQPO14, ACQPO19, --ACQPO20--, ACQPO8, DUMMY0001`

If characters were stripped `ABCD` would equal `ABC`, but `'ABCD' > 'ABC'`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do this in `Oracle`

```
SELECT po.No, po.PoS
FROM PoDetails pod
INNER JOIN Pors po ON po.Id=PoD.PoId
WHERE SUBSTR(po.No, 1, 5) = 'ACPQO'
 AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(po.No, 6, 2)) >= 1
 AND TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(po.No, 6, 2)) <= 20;
```

First `SUBSTR()` is used to match the textual part of the value. Then the numeric part of the values is parsed into a number using `TO_NUMBER()` and made available for numeric comparison between `1` and `20`. (Other databases would also have similar functions to do the same.)

Answer (score 0):

If ACQPO is fixed then try below in SQL Server

```
SELECT po.No, po.PoS
FROM PoDetails pod
INNER JOIN Pors po ON po.Id=PoD.PoId
WHERE left(po.No,5) and 
cast(substring(po.No,6,len(po.No)) as int)
BETWEEN cast(substring('ACQPO1',6,len(po.No)) as int)  AND cast(substring('ACQPO20',6,len(po.No)) as int)


SELECT substring(data,6,len(data)),* FROM #Temp Where 
left(data,5) ='ACQPO' And 
cast(substring(data,6,len(data)) as int)
BETWEEN cast(substring('ACQPO1',6,len(data)) as int)  AND cast(substring('ACQPO20',6,len(data)) as int)
```

Comment: You should clarify the DBMS that this is supposed to work on. Looks like SQL Server

Comment: @MostyMostacho Yes, User taged this question with SQL

Comment: `Structured Query Language` has nothing to do with `SQL Server` :)

Answer (score 0):

FOR MYSQL:-

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
SUBSTR(seq_num, 1,3) = 'ABC'  /* verifying prefix code */
AND
REPLACE(seq_num, 'ABC', '') >= 61440
AND
REPLACE(seq_num, 'ABC', '') <= 61807

**OR**

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE
SUBSTR(seq_num, 1,3) = 'ABC' /* verifying prefix code */
AND
substr(seq_num, 4, length(seq_num)) >= 61440
AND
SUBSTR(seq_num, 4, LENGTH(seq_num)) <= 61807

***works for (like) :***

ABC61447,
ABC61448,
ABC61545,
...,
...,
ABC61807

Answer (score 0):

Just use range 10 to 20 and it works!

```
SELECT po.No,
   po.PoS
FROM PoDetails pod
INNER JOIN Pors po ON po.Id=PoD.PoId
WHERE po.No BETWEEN 'ACQPO10' AND 'ACQPO20'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. Because I do not think that 8 will be sorted between 10 and 20 either (neither numerically nor alphabetically).